# Destructuring in proper way

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In my react application, I have the following component. I have destructured it, but still I have to use, profile.company, profile.user.name etc.

I can destructure like this.

```
const { profile } = props;
const { location } = profile
const { name} = profile.user;
```

But this makes my code ugly. How to destructure the following component in the best way?

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { Header, RouterLink } from '../UI';

const UserInfo = props => {
   const { profile } = props;

   return (
      <div>
         <Header  
            Tag='h3'
            className='text-muted' 
            text={profile.user.name} 
         />

         <Header 
            Tag='h5'
            className='text-muted' 
            text={isEmpty(profile.company) ? 'Currently not employed': `${profile.status} ${profile.company}`}
         />

         <Header 
            Tag='h6'
            className='text-muted' 
            text={isEmpty(profile.location) ? 'Location unknown' : profile.location}
         />

         <RouterLink
            className="btn btn-info"
            route={`/profile/${profile.handle}`}
            text='View Profile'
         />
      </div>
   );
} 

UserInfo.propTypes = { 
   type: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
   className: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
   text: PropTypes.string,
   disabled: PropTypes.bool,

   onClick: PropTypes.func
}

export default UserInfo;
```

Comment: honestly, it looks fine as is. don't use a feature of a language just because it's there. you can always destructure what you need from `profile` and leave it at that level too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends how destructured you want I guess? I would probably not bother destructuring `user` further (although you could if you wanted) and just leave it as:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { Header, RouterLink } from '../UI';

const UserInfo = props => {
   const { user: {name}, company, status, location, handle } = props.profile;

   return (
      <div>
         <Header  
            Tag='h3'
            className='text-muted' 
            text={name} 
         />

         <Header 
            Tag='h5'
            className='text-muted' 
            text={isEmpty(company) ? 'Currently not employed': `${status} ${company}`}
         />

         <Header 
            Tag='h6'
            className='text-muted' 
            text={isEmpty(location) ? 'Location unknown' : location}
         />

         <RouterLink
            className="btn btn-info"
            route={`/profile/${handle}`}
            text='View Profile'
         />
      </div>
   );
} 

UserInfo.propTypes = { 
   type: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
   className: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
   text: PropTypes.string,
   disabled: PropTypes.bool,

   onClick: PropTypes.func
}

export default UserInfo;
```

If you're worried about `profile.user.name` being undefined, you could also change header further:

```
<Header  
    Tag='h3'
    className='text-muted' 
    text={name ? name : 'fallback'} 
/>
```

That's just my thought anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use destructuring like this:

The first we get the **profile** from props, in later maybe you can get more properties from its props (like: account, user, etc, ...), say level 0:

```
const { profile } = props;
```

Then we get the closest nested, say level 1:

```
const  { company, location, handle, profile } = props;
```

Finally, for second closest nested, say level 2:

**Solution 1**

```
const { user: { name } } = profile;
```

or:

**Solution 2**

```
const { user } = profile;
const { name } = user;
```

I prefer the **Solution 2** more, the idea is using destructuring with same level from root for easy maintain.

Answer (score 1):

How about `const { profile: { user: { name }, location, company, status } = props`

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
const UserInfo = ({
  profile: {
    company,
    handle,
    location,
    status,
    user: { name }
  }
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header Tag="h3" className="text-muted" text={name} />

      <Header
        Tag="h5"
        className="text-muted"
        text={
          isEmpty(company) ? "Currently not employed" : `${status} ${company}`
        }
      />

      <Header
        Tag="h6"
        className="text-muted"
        text={isEmpty(location) ? "Location unknown" : location}
      />

      <RouterLink
        className="btn btn-info"
        route={`/profile/${handle}`}
        text="View Profile"
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Reference on destructuring arguments in a method signature.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter)